# jqGrid free multiPageSelect multiselect clear selarrrow

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with multiselect and multiPageSelection. My users can select different rows on different pages between ajax page calls. I've added a custom button and method to the pager to clear the selected rows regardless of page:

```
        $("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager', {
        caption: "Clear",
        title: "Clear Selection",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-circle-close",
        onClickButton: function() {

            $("#grid").setGridParam({ multiPageSelection: false });
            $("#grid").resetSelection();
            $("#grid").setGridParam({ multiPageSelection: true});
        },      
        position: "first"
    });
```

You can see I've had to set multiPageSelection to false, reset the selection and then set multiPageSelection back to true to make this work.

I tried

```
$("#grid").resetSelection();
```

and then one of:

```
$("#grid").setGridParam({ selarrrow: ""});
$("#grid").setGridParam({ selarrrow: []});
$("#grid").setGridParam({ selarrrow: {}});
$("#grid").setGridParam({ selarrrow: null});
```

None of them worked. Either they generated an error or the command was ignored and selarrrow still contained values.

resetSelection only clears the values on the current page if multiPageSelection is true.

Is there a jqgrid command to reset the selection regardless of multiPageSelect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem then you just use wrong way to reset array parameter `selarrrow` (or other parameter like `data`). The most easy way to do that consist of the usage of `getGridParam` instead of `setGridParam`. The call of `getGridParam` *without* an additional parameter returns **the reference** to all internal parameters of jqGrid and you will be easy to replace any array parameter:

```
var $grid = $("#grid"), p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"});
p.selarrrow = [];
```

Alternatively you can use

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { selarrrow: [] }, true);
```

with the second parameter `true`. The last way is a little more readable, but any usage of `setGridParam` is slower as the usage of `getGridParam`.

Comment: That's it! I actually had to do a  $("#grid").resetSelection(); first and then set selarrrow to empty. So...where did you find that or how did you know? I couldn't find the documentation for the free version. What does the true do in setgridparam?

Comment: @Chris: The code of `setGridParam` is short and the code of `getGridParam` is more shorter (see [here](fa-square)). I found that because I implemented the `multiPageSelection` feature. :-) Some information about free jqGrid can be found [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). If you knows (if you use) TypeScript then [the file](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts) could be mostly full documentation. You can see that it has more as 2000 lines. How long would be the documentation?

Comment: Sorry. I meant the "true" parameter. But, I was looking in the wrong file -- the old version of jqgrid. The new version has the "overwrite" parameter. Again, thank you, Oleg. I appreciate it.

Comment: The p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"}); seems to have an extra } and should be p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"); instead (the site won't let me submit such a small change as an edit). Thanks as always for the help, Oleg, 5 years later this fixed my issue also!